# How do you move (mv) in ZSH all files from current directory except two or more to a child directory?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, kali-linux, xargs

(There is plenty of information about this on bash, but much less on zsh and NOT AT ALL for TWO or more files. No idea how to apply the `^` ("caret") TO MORE THAN ONE FILE).

I want to know (see files below), how to move (`mv`) all files to `/test-folder`, EXCEPT TWO files: `a1` and `a2`.

I didn't find any clear syntax (except for bash [looks that with `!(a1|a2)`, would be very easy]) for doing this with TWO or more files.

In `.zsh` the equivalent to `!` looks to be the `^` ("caret"). I could achieve some success with just one, but i cannot find the way to apply the `^` for two or more.

- I found a lot related to bash shell: `shopt -s extglob` (example: `mv !(fileOne) ~/path/newFolder`)
- I found less related to zsh shell: `setopt extendedglob` (example: `mv A/^(file|directory)(|2)(D) B/`)
- Also other ways with `find ... -exec ...` and others with `xargs`, meant "the classical way" by their authors).

Move all files to `/test-folder`, except `a1` and `a2`:

```
~/linux_experiments/MV_CP_ETC$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 Mar 24 15:45 a1
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 Mar 24 15:45 a2
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 Mar 24 15:45 a3
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 Mar 24 15:45 a4
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 Mar 24 15:45 a5
drwxr-xr-x 2 kali kali 4096 Mar 24 16:17 test-folder
```

This is all the far i could go:

```
$ ls
a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  test-folder
                                                                             
$ mv ./^a1 test-folder 
mv: cannot move './test-folder' to a subdirectory of itself, 'test-folder/test-folder'
                                                                             
$ ls -lrt
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 Mar 24 15:45 a1
drwxr-xr-x 2 kali kali 4096 Mar 24 15:56 test-folder
                                                                             
$ cd test-folder
                                                                             
$ ls     
a2  a3  a4  a5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the “not” operator:

```sh
setopt extendedglob
mv ^a[12] testfolder
mv ^a<1-2> testfolder
mv ^(a1|a2) testfolder
```

Or, alternatively, the "but not" operator:

```sh
setopt extendedglob
mv *~a[12] testfolder
mv *~a<1-2> testfolder
mv *~(a1|a2) testfolder
```

(`<x-y>` matches any number between x and y, inclusive.)

See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation

Fun fact: Combining them as `~^` gives you an “and” operator. :)

Comment: what about with full different filenames, instead of "a1 a2", that you pivot through them with the suffix [12]. What about "foo bar". In other words: how and where would you put a list of two or more filenames different in their spelling.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you. Have a look.